# IPython interface to distributed Dask workers over ssh yields "Connection refused"

Tags: ssh, ipython, dask, dask-distributed

Today, I thought I would attempt get to know my workers better through spawning an ipython kernel.  Doing so seemed easy enough using the handy

```py
client.start_ipython_workers()
```

I was able to get the connection information, and then wrote a script to dump it to JSON. I then configured some port forwarding to connect to the worker, however the worker client does not seem to accept connections.

> connect channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

It is possible that I still have some configuration problems with ssh, however I have been successfully connecting to my Jupyter notebook kernel through a similar channel.  Is there some reason why the worker would be blocking connections?

```py
winfo = client.start_ipython_workers()
for worker in winfo.keys():
    winfo[worker]['key']=winfo[worker]['key'].decode('utf8')
with open(os.path.join('/home/centos/kernels/','kernel-'+winfo[worker].pop('ip')+'.json'), 'w+') as f:
    winfo[worker]['ip']='127.0.0.1'
    json.dump(winfo[worker], f,indent=2)
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for port in $(cat $2 | grep '_port' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'); do
echo "establishing tunnel to "$port
ssh $1 -f -N -L $port:127.0.0.1:$port
done
```

Comment: What's the purpose of overwriting `winfo[worker]['ip']`? You only use the keys containing ports anyway.